# Count of distinct with linq to entities and custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, distinct

My custom comparer doesn't seem to be working. I want a count of distinct objects, but I am getting a count of 1 every time. Even though looking at the database itself clearly shows there are more 1 instances of the query with distinct 'TimeOfAction' values.

```
 class TimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Action>
{
    public bool Equals(Action a, Action b)
    {
        if (a.TimeOfAction == b.TimeOfAction)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Action obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Think it could be the GetHashCode method, as I'm not too familiar with how its meant to work. Here is the linq query. I converted to AsEnumerable since Linq to Entities does not support the distinct method.

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

        IEnumerable<Action> query = 
                    from action in db.Action.AsEnumerable()
                    where action.TimeOfAction > new DateTime(2010, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)
                    where action.TimeOfAction < new DateTime(2011, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0)
                    where action.EntityName == "seant"
                    select action;

var count = query.   
            Distinct(new TimeComparer()).Count();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Equals and GetHashCode methods are taking *completely* different approaches. In particular, equal objects may well have different hash codes, assuming `Action.ToString` uses fields other than TimeOfAction. They have to be aligned, or you're going to have absolutely no chance of getting reasonable results. It's okay for unequal objects to have the same hashcode (although that will hinder performance) but equal objects *must* give the same hash code.

Note that using a custom comparer will force the Distinct part to be done in-process rather than in the database. That may well not be a problem, you just need to understand it. EDIT: I hadn't spotted that there's an overload of `Queryable.Distinct` which *does* take an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. My guess is that that's so you can provide custom string comparers and a few other well-known comparers... not just arbitrary code. If it works, it's going to be done locally anyway. I wouldn't be surprised if it just blew up though.

EDIT: As Marc says, you can use `Select(x => x.TimeOfAction).Distinct().Count()` to do this in the database. You'll need to remove the call to `AsEnumerable` too though. My guess is that that's there because something else wasn't working. You could try this:

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
IQueryable<DateTime> query = 
            from action in db.Action
            where action.TimeOfAction > new DateTime(2010, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)
            where action.TimeOfAction < new DateTime(2011, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0)
            where action.EntityName == "seant"
            select action.TimeOfAction;
var count = query.Distinct().Count();
```

Of course if you needed `query` for something else you'd need to keep the original version too:

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
IQueryable<Action> query = 
            from action in db.Action
            where action.TimeOfAction > new DateTime(2010, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)
            where action.TimeOfAction < new DateTime(2011, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0)
            where action.EntityName == "seant"
            select action;

var count = query.Select(x => x.TimeOfAction).Distinct().Count();
// Use query here as well to get at full action details
```

Note that using query again will produce a second database query. You'll need to look at what's going on in terms of transactions if you need the count to be consistent with whatever the second query does... or pull all the details from the database (using a `ToList` call) and then do the Distinct part in-process.

---

Back to custom equality comparers...

Assuming `TimeOfAction` is a `DateTime` or some other type which has a reasonable hash code, you can change your class to:

```
class TimeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Action>
{
    public bool Equals(Action a, Action b)
    {
        return a.TimeOfAction == b.TimeOfAction;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Action obj)
    {
        return obj.TimeOfAction.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Note that I've also simplified your `Equals` method - any time you find yourself with:

```
if (condition)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

you can simplify it to:

```
return condition;
```

Comment: Nice detail (still uses `IEnumerable<>` though?).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, note that that *isn't* going to run at the db server, so this isn't really related to EF.

I *suspect* it is *in part* because your `GetHashCode` doesn't agree with `Equals`; you should ideally have something like:

```
public int GetHashCode(Action obj)
{
    return obj.TimeOfAction.GetHashCode();
}
```

since that is what your `Equals` cares about.

Also, however, note that the entire query could be re-written (and will probably work at the db server if you use `IQueryable<Action> query` (and remove the `AsEnumerable()`), rather than `IEnumerable<Action> query`) with:

```
var count = query.Select(x => x.TimeOfAction).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: +1 for the last bit, which is what I was about to add to my answer. I'll leave my answer up for at least a while, as I think the point about simplifying the Equals method is worth the OP seeing. I'm happy for you to include it in your answer though, and then I'll delete mine :)

Comment: ... note the call to AsEnumerable though. He'll need to remove that too :)

Comment: @Jon - actually, I *think* the OP is referring to the implicit cast, but I've added it anyway

Comment: @Marc: I've now gone into a certain amount of detail around this in my answer too... particularly around multiple database queries etc.

Comment: So If I leave it as an IQueryable (the usual way) everything happens at the db server, and thats why the Distinct(IEqualityComparer) method fails w/out casting to IEnumerable first? 

Made the suggested changes and it worked, thanks. Just wondering can I still use these IEqualityComparer classes or should I just drop them?

Comment: @Sean: Unless you actually need them, drop them. If you really need to use them, then call AsEnumerable as late as you can, to get as much work done by the DB as possible.

Comment: @Sean ; to echo @Jon's comment - any code you don't *need* is just an extra source of potential bugs for no reason; drop 'em ;p